# Insert and Update commands after a LOOP statement

Tags: mysql, loops, insert

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in MySql, which needs to proceed with further updates after a END LOOP tag, just like in the code below.

Somehow, the insert command after the the END LOOP tag is not getting executed, can someone tell my why? How do I go about solving this?

```
BEGIN
/**Constant variables*/
DECLARE constX  FLOAT DEFAULT 2.660;
DECLARE constMR FLOAT DEFAULT 3.268;

/**Variables for tbSell*/
DECLARE seID, prodID INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE qttSell, xV FLOAT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE previousQttSell, previousXV FLOAT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE sPrice, xAvgV, mRAvgV, xUclV, xLclV, mRUclV FLOAT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE sDt DATE DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE crQttSell CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT ts.`sellQuantity`
    FROM tb_sell ts
    WHERE ts.`productID` = 1;

/**Truncating temp tables*/
TRUNCATE tb_metrics;
TRUNCATE `tb_mr_temp_table`;

OPEN crQttSell;
get_QttSell: LOOP
    FETCH crQttSell INTO qttSell;    
    INSERT INTO tb_metrics VALUES('', 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 555);    
    SET previousQttSell = qttSell;    
END LOOP get_QttSell;
CLOSE crQttSell;

INSERT INTO tb_metrics VALUES('', 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7);

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You must detect an EOF condition after a fetch statement to avoid infinite loop:

```
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
  ....
  ....
  get_QttSell: LOOP
    FETCH crQttSell INTO qttSell;   
    IF done THEN
      LEAVE get_QttSell;
    END IF; 
    INSERT INTO tb_metrics VALUES('', 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 555);    
    SET previousQttSell = qttSell;    
  END LOOP get_QttSell;
  ....
```

read documentation for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cursors.html